# MYSQL Subquery with filtered result from multi table query

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I am trying to create a query that returns a result based on the following:

The script works for me right now but I am needing to perform an additional step. I need to figure out how to  filters out the result for any 'activity.dest_id' that is not yet confirmed in the 'user_requests' table and apply it only to the last value in the 'IN'. In the example the value would be 'Bill' all other values like 'Fashion, Art, Architecture' do not have to be checked against the user_requests table as these values are things not people. Thanks for the help.

```
SELECT a.activity_type, a.dest_id, o.opinion_id, o.fromUser, o.image_data, o.votedYes, o.votedNo, o.created_at, o.expires_at
FROM activity a, opinions o
WHERE a.opinion_id = o.opinion_id
AND NOT
EXISTS (
SELECT opinion_id, fromUser
FROM user_activity u
WHERE u.opinion_id = a.opinion_id
)
AND a.dest_id
IN (
"Fashion", "Art", "Architecture", "Bill"
)
```

```
 user_activity table
+------------+-----------+
| opinion_id | fromuser 
------------+-----------+ 
| 9          | Jim   
| 10         | Sam  
+------------+-----------+
```

```
 user_requests table
+------------+-----------+---------+
| fromUser | toUser | type | status
------------+-----------+----------+ 
| Ana      | Bill   | C    |   1
| Kate     | Bill   | P    |   0
+------------+-----------+---------+
```

```
 activity table
+------------+-------+
| fromUser | dest_id
------------+--------+ 
| Ana      | Fashion   
| Ana      | Art   
| Kate     | Bill   
| Tom      | Fashion   
| Bill     | Fashion   
| Kim      | Art   
| Kim      | Art  
| Ana      | Fashion
| Kim      | Ana
+------------+-------+
```

```
 opinion table
+------------+-----------+---------+------------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| opinion_id | fromUser | image_data | votedYes | votedNo | created_at | expires_at
+------------+-----------+---------+------------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 1          | Ana      | non        |   1      |  3      | 2014-12-17 | 2014-12-18 
| 2          | Ana      | non        |   1      |  3      | 2014-12-17 | 2014-12-18 
| 3          | Ana      | non        |   1      |  3      | 2014-12-17 | 2014-12-18 
| 4          | Ana      | non        |   1      |  3      | 2014-12-17 | 2014-12-18 
| 5          | Ana      | non        |   1      |  3      | 2014-12-17 | 2014-12-18 
+------------+-----------+---------+------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a join.
I am right in assuming that you need to join the fromuser in the user_activity table with the fromuser in the user_requests table.

Does P = Pending
and C = Confirmed

If this is correct,

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT a.activity_type, a.dest_id, o.opinion_id, o.fromUser, o.image_data, o.votedYes, o.votedNo, o.created_at, o.expires_at
FROM activity a, opinions o
WHERE a.opinion_id = o.opinion_id
AND NOT
EXISTS (
SELECT opinion_id, fromUser
FROM user_activity u
WHERE u.opinion_id = a.opinion_id
)
AND a.dest_id
IN (
"Fashion", "Art", "Architecture", "Bill"
)
) x INNER JOIN user_requests ON x.fromUser = user_requests.fromUser
WHERE user_requests.type = 'C'
```

This is probably not the best efficient way to do it, and it is also untested, but it seemed the most logical with your query.